# How to split out input content by comma and apply css to each element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a text box where in user inputs email addresses separated by `,` what I want to achieve is to set the `background-color: green` of text entered by user till `comma`, and so on for each text before `,` currently it is applying background-color to text-box directly and not to only text itself for each text before comma

```js
 $('.team-btn').click(function() {
  $('.team-intro').replaceWith($(".team-invite").clone().show());

  $('#invite-emails').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188) {
      $(this).addClass('foo');
    }
  });

  });
```

```css
.foo{
    background-color:#0c0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="team-intro">
            <p>XXXX is a Free to use, Invite your team and get started today</p>
            <button class="team-btn">Invite Now</button>
        </div>

        <div class="team-invite" style="display:none;">
            <p>Enter emails and we will invite your mates to join you.</p>
            <input type="text" id='invite-emails' name='email'  placeholder='enter emails here' size="30">
            <br>
            <!--<div data-value=""  id='style-email' style="padding-left: 12px; padding-right: 12px;">-->
            <p id='subtext'>You can enter multiple emails with comma</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('#invite-emails').tagsInput({
  'width': 'auto',
  'delimiter': ',',
  'defaultText': 'Enter email',
  onAddTag: function(item) {
    $($(".tagsinput").get(0)).find(".tag").each(function() {
      if (!ValidateEmail($(this).text().trim().split(/(\s+)/)[0])) {
        $(this).addClass("badtag");
      }
    });
  },
  'onChange': function(item) {
        $($(".tagsinput").get(0)).find(".tag").each(function() {
      if (!ValidateEmail($(this).text().trim().split(/(\s+)/)[0])) {
        $(this).addClass("badtag");
      }
    });
  }

});
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6aa2adba/)

I used the jQuery Tags Input library and then added the email validation alongside and wrote classes for highlighting bad emails in red.

And I implemented it this way because you cannot highlight individual text backgrounds in html input and textareas.

Comment: Awesome..Its  more than my expectations!!!!Wonderful..working flawlessly..thanks a lot buddy

Comment: How do you achieve the same effect without JQuery (with plain JS)?